# PHP App Response Time Increases as Concurrency Increases

Tags: php, nginx, concurrency, jmeter

I'm trying to diagnose poor response times for a php application when concurrency increases.

A php application is running with a mysql db connection open and session being created.  JMeter tests are being ran to test concurrency.  As concurrency increases I am also seeing response times increase in a linear growth rate.  The result is that the application can only handle a small concurrency level.

XDebug has been used to profile the application code which uses a third party framework; however, other than decreasing the application response time per request there is no solid explanation for the steady response time increase with concurrency.

CPU usage is under 60% and load average is low.  There is plenty of memory avail.

A basic "hello world" php file has been setup to test NGINX/PHP-FPM.  Under high concurrency the response times for this file remain pretty constant.

I'm having trouble identifying the root cause of the response time increase with concurrency while system vitals appear to be ok.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Tools?

Suspect areas?

Comment: What database engine are you using? Does the application use the filesystem? Are you using any opcache? Is there any single resource that all the threads could be in contention for? A linear growth rate suggests each thread perhaps waiting for the previous to complete and release a resource before it can access something they all share

Comment: All InnoDB with exception of 1 MyISAM table.  There is a small configuration file stored and used (FS).  opcache is enabled.  I agree that the application may be becoming thread bound.  That explains the linear response time growth.  The problem I'm having is finding where this is happening.  XDebug is not helping...

Comment: New Relic provides pretty detailed application side performance specs and is very PHP friendly. I'm not related to the company but we use them ourselves.

Comment: TBH, we've been using newrelic and it helps but NOT to the extent that there was an obvious answer.  The application server CPU seemed ok in newrelic; however, using htop on the server indicated a 4 cores using 100% CPU load average of over 5 times.  The application code is blocking and expensive to execute.  The problem is I can't find any blocking code with xdebug or a code walkthrough.  There has to be a better tool!!!  There is no way an app server can only handle a low concurrency like this and be vaible